# Using `push` on jQuery collection

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery collections are [array-like Objects](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/) with a length property and methods from `Array.prototype` like [`splice`, `sort`, and `push`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/bb026fc12c3c2ad37f47f0919e484bddcdc3d291/src/core.js#L111-L113). I'm aware that those methods are not chainable like typical jQuery methods, but the methods do work as expected.

Are there any reasons not to manipulate jQuery collections using those `Array.prototype` methods such as browser compatibility or issues with other jQuery methods?

## Example

In a loop, add elements to a jQuery collection for later manipulation.

```
var $divs = $(); // Create empty jQuery collection.
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = i+1;
  $divs.push(div); // Add newly created div to collection
}
$divs.addClass('red').appendTo(document.body);
```

[View on Codepen](http://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/oXaWqK?editors=011)

Using `push` here instead of `$divs = $divs.add(div);` is more succinct and seems more efficient. If [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/) were working right now, I'm sure it would show better performance with `push`.

Comment: I never even used .add to do this :)

Comment: Why don't you use a _#document-fragment_ and then if you really want _jQuery_ `$divs = $(fragment).children()`?

Comment: @PaulS. The code is purely for example. The elements could be existing DOM elements collected another way or you could just add elements to an array that's later turned into a jQuery collection with `$(myArray)`. However, the main idea/question here is if it's okay to slip an element into an existing collection using `push`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is `.add` from the jQuery source:

```
add: function( selector, context ) {
  return this.pushStack(
    jQuery.uniqueSort(
      jQuery.merge( this.get(), jQuery( selector, context ) )
    )
  );
},
```

In this function 3 more methods are called... [`.merge`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/), [`.uniqueSort`](https://gist.github.com/JamenMarz/a207aa49e9907f21ab01) (which is actually [SizzleJS](http://sizzlejs.com/)), and [`.pushStack`](http://api.jquery.com/pushstack/)...

In addition to just `.push`, jQuery will:

- Merge your input if it's an array of selectors. (`.merge`)
- Remove any duplicate entries. (`.uniqueSort`)
- Accept flexible input with DOM elements (`.pushStack`)

So, to conclude that, if you're worried about input, `.add` is good to use, since jQuery makes it flexible (regular DOM or jQuery objects work), but it also removes duplicate entries and can take in multiple items with an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an [***Array* into *jQuery***](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-elementArray), this means you can make full use of a native *Array*

```
// build
var j, el, ly = [];
for (j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
    el = document.createElement('span');
    ly.push(el);
}
// wrap
var jq = $(ly); // jQuery object [<span>, <span>, <span>]
```

Adding more elements can be done with [*pushStack*](http://api.jquery.com/pushstack/) and another *Array*

```
jq.pushStack([document.createElement('div')]);
jq; // [<span>, <span>, <span>, <div>]
```

Or more generally using [*add*](http://api.jquery.com/add/) which accepts any input the normal *jQuery* constructor takes

```
jq.add(document.createElement('hr'));
jq; //  [<span>, <span>, <span>, <div>, <hr>]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The example is purely an example, and I'm aware of the other ways to add elements to a collection. My question is whether or not `push` is 'safe' to use or if there are reasons against using it for adding single elements to a collection.